# Getting key and value of attributes in xml tag

Tags: python, xml, xpath, tags, lxml

So If I had this following tag:

```
<ana lex="ун" morph="ың" gr="NUM,poss.2sg" trans="десять" />
```

I want to extract not just the value but more specifically the names of the attributes. I have already tried using the names function like so (where ana is the above tag):

```
 at_names = ana.xpath('name(@*)')
```

However, this only returns the first attribute name 'lex'. How could I get a list of all attribute names in a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `.items` to get the name and value:

```
In [3]: import  lxml.etree as et

In [4]: x = et.fromstring("""<ana lex="ун" morph="ың" gr="NUM,poss.2sg" trans="десять" />""")

In [5]: x.attrib
Out[5]: {'trans': 'десять', 'lex': 'ун', 'gr': 'NUM,poss.2sg', 'morph': 'ың'}

In [6]: x.items()
Out[6]: [('lex', 'ун'), ('morph', 'ың'), ('gr', 'NUM,poss.2sg'), ('trans', 'десять')]
```

Or just .keys to get the names:

```
In [7]: x.keys()
Out[7]: ['lex', 'morph', 'gr', 'trans']
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea there was literally an attribute called 'attrib'. Worked great!